# Texto mal traducido en historial de reportes

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones

Estaba revisando el historial de reportes realizados y existen textos que faltan por traducir, a continuación dejo una captura de los mismos.

[image: Textos sin traduccion]

Comment: Alguna recomendación de qué debería decir?

Comment: La primera podría ser: Los reportes no deben utilizarse para indicar errores técnicos, o una respuesta erronea. La siguiente podría ser: un moderador revisó tu reporte, pero no encontró ninguna evidencia para apoyarlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las cadenas de texto siguen cambiando y veremos más y más que necesitan traducirse.  Es parte de la expansión del sitio.  Las que reportaste aquí se han corregido.